# Problems with Jquery/Javascript on.("tap touch touchstart")

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I'm creating a website, so i was making a menu for the mobile version. I thought phones/tablets automaticly reacted to .on('click'), but apparently they don't. I've downloaded the lastest jquery library, but it still doesn't work. On a computer webbrowser it works perfectly but not on my ipad. Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong? I tried to look for different posts where people had the same problems, but it didn't work for me. I tried touch, touchstart, touchend, tap, vclick,....

This is in my document.ready

```
    $('#muziekTrue').on('click touchstart', muziekToevoegen);
    $('#muziekFalse').on('click touchstart', muziekNietToevoegen);
```

This is my function:

```
    showMenuKlein = function(){
         var open = $("#menuklein>ul").hasClass("open");
         if (open === false) {
             $("#menuklein ul").slideDown( "slow").addClass("open");
          }
         else {
             $("#menuklein ul").slideUp( "slow").removeClass("open");
          }
      };
```

Comment: they both work, which means they cancel out and the toggle is so fast as to be instant. if you use a web-app-capable meta you can use click() without pain on mobile...

Comment: Could you please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run? I've been working with touch events on iPad recently and haven't experienced that problem.

Comment: Could you please let us know which version of jQuery library currently included on project ?

Comment: @dandavis I'm using <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> as meta, is there another way for this?

Comment: @MikeC I can't now i will try to do it as fast as possible

Comment: @Plycoder i'm using jquery library 3.1.1